# Am I doing something wrong with importing Oculus Integration in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

When I go to the Asset Store in Unity and import the Oculus Integration I get 63 error messages.

I have tried re-installing Unity, it didn't work. I can't find anyone else having similar issues.

Error Messages:

Assets\Oculus\VR\Scripts\Util\OVRCursor.cs(22,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Assets\Oculus\VR\Scripts\Util\OVRInputModule.cs(25,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PointerInputModule' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\Oculus\VR\Scripts\Util\OVRInputModule.cs(432,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MouseState' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

There is many more like this, suggesting files are missing.

Unity Version 2019.3.0a3

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this solves this problem, but either there is something wrong with Unity (tested 2019.2.0b4, 2019.1.4f1, and the 2019.3 versions) or Oculus Integration.

Add and a reference to Unity.ugui in Unity like in the picture.
[image: unity oculus vr ui problem]

I encountered a couple of compiler error as well, but those could just be commented as it was in sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run Unity Hub with administration rights and import Oculus Integration again

Answer (score 0):

All `VR` components were renamed to `XR`.

Just double click on the errors and replace the lines of the Using statement with `XR`
e.g.

OVRTracker.cs

```
using VR = UnityEngine.VR;

// is changed to

using XR = UnityEngine.XR;
```

And the error will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced VR with XR and it worked for everything except one boundary error.

Comment: this seems like the same answer given above on Dec 20 --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/65376976/10278

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing any existing Oculus package and deleting the library folder before re-downloading and importing? This seems to fix the issues on many Oculus updates. As they're aggressively updating stuff across SDK versions, it causes a lot of conflicts while just updating